# Parse datagram from recvmsg on a raw socket

Tags: icmp, recvmsg

I'm trying to parse a datagram obtained with `recvmsg` on a raw socket, but I'm not sure about its format. Since according to `man raw`, "A raw socket receives or sends the raw datagram not including link level headers", I was expecting that it would start directly with the ip header. But reading this other question [sockets: right way to access IP and UDP headers on raw socket buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690306/sockets-right-way-to-access-ip-and-udp-headers-on-raw-socket-buffer), in which the ip header is obtained with

```
  struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *)(pkt + 14);
```

it looks like there are 14 bytes before it. What are those bytes reserved for? Can I assume I will always get the ip header on a raw sockets' datagram at that position?

I created the socket in this way

```
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

sent an `icmp` request using `sendto` with a `struct icmphdr` (with `ICMP_TYPE`, internet checksum ,etc) and received 28 bytes from `recvmsg` (passing MSG_WAITALL flag) I would like to parse.